# I tried to use JFrame method and thing went like hell as on the picture

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


/**
 * Created by Admins on 1/12/2559.
 */
public class Main extends JFrame {

    public Main(){
        setVisible(true);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,400));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        Label l =new Label("sss");
        new Main().add(l);

    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Main t = new Main();
        t.start();
    }


    private void start() {
        System.out.println("RUNNING");
    }
}
```

[image]

I know it's not about the typo but can anyone tell me how to fix this problem

Comment: Please show us your code!

Comment: Please add some more details like class file or function etc.

Comment: What do you think will happen if you invoke new Main() at the end of new Main() ?

Answer (score 2):

This effect occures, because in the constructor of `Main`, you always create a new `JFrame`, which then also creates a `Main`-object...

To solve this problem, remove the `new Main().` before `add(l)`. By doing this, you add the label to the Frame itself, not a new created Frame.

Additional hint: use `JLabel` instead of `Label`. Thats the swing-variant instead of the awt-variant (newer approach).

Comment: Another point: add the label *before* making the frame visible.